# How to update and delete custom list view items

Tags: android, listview

In android I am beginner I want to update and delete custom list view items.So provide me a sample code.

Comment: do you normally demand stuff? with no effort or attempt shown by yourself?

Comment: Nobody here is going to write your code for you. Show us what you tried so far and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Provide us with money first :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code.

Delete

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)getListView().getAdapter();
myAdapter.remove(myAdapter.getItem(pos));
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Refresh the List, call that Activity once again Using Intent